# SQL Server : AND OR statement

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a procedure to pull all the records from an `Error` table.

It should only pull the value when the `Error` column is not NULL or Empty

```
Declare @StatementKey INT AS 

Select Distinct 
    error.ErrorMessage,
    row.RowNumber,
    Statement.StatementKey,
    Statement.StatementName
From 
    Statement 
Join 
    Row row ON row.FK_StatementKey = Statement.Pk_StatementKey
Join 
    ErrorTable error ON row.RowNumber = error.RowNumber 
Where 
    Statement.StatementKey = @StatementKey 
    AND (error.ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL OR error.ErrorMessage <> '')
```

I did this but it still pulls rows with an EMPTY `ErrorMessage` column

But when I do

```
AND (error.ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL)
AND (error.ErrorMessage <> '')
```

Then it will not pull the EMPTY VALUE AS WELL AS NULL

Can someone tell me a easier way and maybe tell me WHY?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last AND statement in your first query is incorrect. You should replace it with this:

```
AND NOT(error.ErrorMessage IS NULL OR error.ErrorMessage = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coalesce:

```
Coalesce(error.ErrorMessage,'')<>''
```